# How to migrate out of the box workflows to Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

As far as I know, SharePoint Designer workflows can be exported as templates and can be reused. But for out of the box workflows such as Three Stage, Publishing Approval, Approval and all the other workflows, once I have created them, how do I migrate that similar workflow when we move to Office 365?

Is there some way to export it or do we have to recreate those workflows?

Comment: Have same requirement, any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

OOTB workflows available in the o365 depends upon on the Plan. I am wondering why you want to migrate OOTB workflow?

Check the below link to see all the available workflows(5), for some you need to activate them.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-help/about-the-workflows-included-with-sharepoint-HA102771434.aspx

If still you want then i think best solution is 3rd party tools for migration from on-prem to Online. You can try using ShareGate,Metalogix etc

Comment: I'm not migrating the OOTB workflows from Office 365. What I was asking was how to migrate OOTB workflows from On Premise SharePoint sites (eg. Approval Workflows) Since the ones you create and associate with the list do not show up in SharePoint Designer I was assuming there is another way to migrate these workflows rather than recreating them when I move my objects to OFfice 365.

Answer (score -1):

You can migrate a workflow *definition* by deploying the workflow to your SharePoint Online site. Individual *instances* of workflows cannot be migrated, either to the cloud or from one on-premise system to another.